# Python Sorting Lists Based On Score

Tags: python

I'm totally new to python(just started it)and I need some help for this code I wrote which doesn't seem to work .my intention is to sort each user by their score written in front of them  so input looks like :

```
user1 87.26
user2 65.10
user3 12.3
```

and out put should sort them based on their number in front of them(their score), so the code looks like this, but it doesn't work :

```
score= []
classlist = []
def getinfo () :
    global infolist
    info_input = input()
    if  info_input== "show res":
        validation()
    else :

        classlist.append(info_input.split())
        getinfo()

def validation():
    global infolist
    for each_data in classlist:
        score.append(float(each_data[1]))
        score.sort()
    str(score)
    for eachscore in score :
        for eachuser in classlist:
            if eachscore in eachuser:
                print(eachuser)

getinfo()
```

Comment: could you please add the error message or unexpected output you get, so its more clear whats wrong and what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom comparator with the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) function to sort on scores, and `reverse=True` to sort in descending order:

```
def validation():
    for user, score in sorted(classlist, key=lambda pair: pair[1], reverse=True):
        print(user, score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sorted()` function

```py
users = ["user1 87.26", "user2 65.10", "user3 12.3"]
sortedUsers = sorted(users, key=lambda k: k.split()[1])
```

Output

```
['user3 12.3', 'user2 65.10', 'user1 87.26']
```

To sort by descending, simply call the `reverse()` method on the list.

```py
sortedUsers.reverse()
```

Output

```
['user1 87.26', 'user2 65.10', 'user3 12.3']
```